# NetworkStream.Read not receive all data

Tags: c#, image, sockets, stream, networkstream

I'm using C# to write a code for sending an image
Everything works perfectly when I'm writing or reading from `localhost` as the IP (same PC)
but when I use another PC for reading, I'm getting an error; the image sometimes is only half image, quarter of the image and sometimes nothing

This is the reading code

```
byte[] readBytes(int length)
{
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
    int recv=  stream.Read(bytes, 0, length);
    while (recv < length)
    {
        length -= recv;
        recv = stream.Read(bytes, recv, length);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

I think my while loop is incorrect. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your while loop is not correct. First, the condition is wrong. Imagine that each call to `Read` receives just one byte (try it on a piece of paper if this is not clear). Also, if it loops more than once, `Read` will write to the wrong place in the buffer. That's why it works on the localhost: the connection is almost instantaneous and the first `Read` receives everything.